# how to set datePickerMode in a fragment?

Tags: android, material-design, datetimepicker

In the android code ,I use a DatePickerDialog to choose the date.it behaves differently in android material design and the previous versions.So how can I set fix this question to let material design behaves the same as before in java code ?

Answer (score 5):

Change DatePicker Mode in DatePickerDialog in Lollipop devices

Try this,

create style in **values-v21**

```
<style name="style_date_picker_dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/style_date_picker</item>
    </style>

    <style name="style_date_picker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
```

and in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button button;
    private DatePickerDialog mDatePickerDialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, R.style.style_date_picker_dialog, dateSetListener, 2015, 10, 16);
                } else {
                    mDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, dateSetListener, 2015, 10, 16);
                }
                mDatePickerDialog.setTitle("Select Date");
                mDatePickerDialog.show();

            }
        });


    }

    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            mDatePickerDialog.dismiss();
        }
    };

}
```

I hope it is helpful to you.