# DatePickerDialog Holo styling failed on Android 7 Nougat

Tags: java, android, calendar

From our customer demand we want to keep the HOLO style on the DatePickerDialog for all Android OS version, sth like:
[DatePicker on Android 7-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qriHZ.png)

But it seems to not to work correctly on Android 7:

[DatePicker on Android 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KISrY.png)

**From my implementation:**

```
new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT,
                        mCalendarPickerListener,
                        calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

It's working fine for prior android 7. Anybody has the same issue?

Edited: solution is found to be fixed in API 25
https://code.google.com/u/106133255289400340786/

Comment: Have you updated your support library?

Comment: @Shuddh already tried but still the same :) I tried '24.2.1' https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: I'm also running into this problem. Anyone have a solution?

Comment: my solution was to push back the native picker style. Not enforcing HOLO_LIGHT anymore...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I use a `DatePickerDialog` to prompt users for their birthdays. Unfortunately, I've received a number of complaints from users about the Material-themed dialog when trying it, so switching to it is not an option for me: I have to stick to the Holo-themed dialog.

It turns out that Android 7.0 shipped with a bug: trying to use the Holo theme on this platform instead falls back to using a **broken** Material theme for the `DatePickerDialog`. See these two bug reports:

- [Issue 222808](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222808)
- [Issue 222208](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222208)

I used a modified form of [this workaround by Jeff Lockhart](https://gist.github.com/jeffdgr8/6bc5f990bf0c13a7334ce385d482af9f) referenced in those bug reports:

```
private static final class FixedHoloDatePickerDialog extends DatePickerDialog {
    private FixedHoloDatePickerDialog(Context context, OnDateSetListener callBack,
                                      int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        super(context, callBack, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        // Force spinners on Android 7.0 only (SDK 24).
        // Note: I'm using a naked SDK value of 24 here, because I'm
        // targeting SDK 23, and Build.VERSION_CODES.N is not available yet.
        // But if you target SDK >= 24, you should have it.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 24) {
            try {
                final Field field = this.findField(
                        DatePickerDialog.class,
                        DatePicker.class,
                        "mDatePicker"
                );

                final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) field.get(this);
                final Class<?> delegateClass = Class.forName(
                        "android.widget.DatePicker$DatePickerDelegate"
                );
                final Field delegateField = this.findField(
                        DatePicker.class,
                        delegateClass,
                        "mDelegate"
                );

                final Object delegate = delegateField.get(datePicker);
                final Class<?> spinnerDelegateClass = Class.forName(
                        "android.widget.DatePickerSpinnerDelegate"
                );

                if (delegate.getClass() != spinnerDelegateClass) {
                    delegateField.set(datePicker, null);
                    datePicker.removeAllViews();

                    final Constructor spinnerDelegateConstructor =
                            spinnerDelegateClass.getDeclaredConstructor(
                                    DatePicker.class,
                                    Context.class,
                                    AttributeSet.class,
                                    int.class,
                                    int.class
                            );
                    spinnerDelegateConstructor.setAccessible(true);

                    final Object spinnerDelegate = spinnerDelegateConstructor.newInstance(
                            datePicker,
                            context,
                            null,
                            android.R.attr.datePickerStyle,
                            0
                    );
                    delegateField.set(datePicker, spinnerDelegate);

                    datePicker.init(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, this);
                    datePicker.setCalendarViewShown(false);
                    datePicker.setSpinnersShown(true);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) { /* Do nothing */ }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Find Field with expectedName in objectClass. If not found, find first occurrence of
     * target fieldClass in objectClass.
     */
    private Field findField(Class objectClass, Class fieldClass, String expectedName) {
        try {
            final Field field = objectClass.getDeclaredField(expectedName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            return field;
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) { /* Ignore */ }

        // Search for it if it wasn't found under the expectedName.
        for (final Field field : objectClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (field.getType() == fieldClass) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

What this does is:

- Get the private `DatePicker mDatePicker` field belonging to this dialog
- Get the private `DatePickerDelegate mDelegate` field belonging to this dialog
- Check that the delegate is not already an instance of `DatePickerSpinnerDelegate` (the type of delegate we want)
- Remove all views from the `DatePicker`, since they are the Material calendar widgets
- Create a new instance of `DatePickerSpinnerDelegate`, and assign it to the `mDelegate` field of `mDatePicker` of this dialog
- Re-initialize `mDatePicker` with calendar info and some params to get it to inflate the spinners

---

To use this workaround, I create a `ContextThemeWrapper` around my `Context`, which allows me to set a theme, in this case Holo:

```
final Context themedContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(
        this.getContext(),
        android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog
);

final DatePickerDialog dialog = new FixedHoloDatePickerDialog(
        themedContext,
        datePickerListener,
        calender.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
```

---

**Notes**:

- This uses reflection to access private fields. Generally, this is not a robust approach and you can't count on it. I'm mitigating the risk here by 1) restricting this to a single SDK version, v24; and 2) wrapping the entire bit of reflection code in a `try {...} catch (Exception e) {/* NOP */}` block, so if any of the reflection fails, nothing will happen and the (sadly broken) default Material fallback will be used.
- The bug reports above claim that this issue has been fixed in Android 7.1 (SDK 25). I have not tested this.
- The [original workaround code](https://gist.github.com/jeffdgr8/6bc5f990bf0c13a7334ce385d482af9f) was for `TimePickerDialog` that suffered from a similar problem. I've modified it to work with `DatePickerDialog` instead, and also simplified the solution to be less generic, and more specific to my exact use case. However, you could use the more complete original version and just tweak it for `Date` instead of `Time`.

Comment: even though it's a work around issue but thanks anyway, this sounds workable

Comment: sounds like the correct FIX should be using API 25
https://code.google.com/u/106133255289400340786/

Comment: set date listener doesnt work, always returning the init date

Comment: thanks, it's working! but the text and lines colour are white, how can I change this ?

Answer (score 0):

Date picker has it's own separate style https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.style.html#Widget_DatePicker

I think you need `R.style.Widget.Holo.DatePicker`instead of `AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT`. It's possible you may need to create your own empty style that has `@android:style/Widget.Holo.DatePicker` as it's parent and use that.

Comment: it doesn't work correctly, instead it shows a full screen calendar with blank gaps.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [solution by savanto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40989508/8876284): As of API 28 Holo Light Theme is deprecated. If you target API 21 / Lollipop devices and newer you should use Material design styles, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33162525/8876284). I defined these styles and then linked to `R.style.dlg_datePicker` in the `ContextThemeWrapper`:

```
<style name="dlg_datePicker" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/datePicker_style</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
</style>

<style name="datePicker_style" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following it is working. I have tested. And it does not have blank gaps.

Also `mDatePickerListener` is my DatePickerListner which you can create.

```
//Setting theme to android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog  
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog,
                    mDatePickerListener,
                    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

datePicker.setCancelable(false);
datePicker.setTitle(getString(R.string.select_your_dob));
//This line is important to remove blank gaps
datePicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
datePicker.show();
```

Comment: This does *not* work on HTC One M or Samsung Galaxy A5-2016 as of Android 7 / API 24: It gives the Date Picker in Calendar mode, *not* in Spinner Mode.